# SVNKit not installing using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse-juno, svnkit

- Requirement: The users of a Java program I want to develop should be able to version files using Subversion through my Java code
- System details:windows XP 32 bit , Eclipse Juno
- Problem:not able to install svnkit plugin to eclipse juno

I did the following on my Eclipse Juno, windows 32 bit machine:

- Help->Add new Software-> 'Available Software' tab
- Click 'Add Site...' button
- Type http://eclipse.svnkit.com/1.7.x/ in the 'Location' field and press 'OK'.
- Check the new site (it should appear in the list of update sites) and follow further steps as prompted by Eclipse.

  1. I did not get any further steps from eclipse
  2. I am getting an error "Site not find .."
     [image: screenshot of the same]

Comment: It looks like a connectivity problem; I can't reproduce this error using Eclipse Kepler. Can you open the url http://eclipse.svnkit.com/1.7.x/ in a web-browser?

Comment: The update site also loads fine to me. Check your internet connections, like proxy and firewalls.

Answer (score 1):

To integrate SVNKit in your Java program, you should do the following steps:

1. Go to the [Download page](http://svnkit.com/download.php) of SVNKit.
2. Decide which Subversion version you want to support, in your case, 1.7.11 should be the best fit.
3. Download the [standalone version](http://www.svnkit.com/org.tmatesoft.svn_1.7.11.standalone.zip) which contains the whole libraries you will have to include into your program.
4. Decide where to store these libraries, so you have access to them during development. Often people use here a sub-directory `libs` in their source code.
5. Only store the content of the lib directory into that location. The other parts may be useful as well, and your are able to see the source code of SVNKit by referencing the Zip-File you have downloaded, but that is another story.
6. Try out one of [their examples](http://wiki.svnkit.com/Printing_Out_A_Subversion_Repository_Tree) to see if your installation is correct and does work.

At the end, you have to solve the problem as well how to deploy your program, so that users may use it, but this could be addressed in another question :-)

And of course, the recipe would be different, when you want to use Maven for development in Java.

So your misunderstanding was, that when you develop in Eclipse, you have to take the Eclipse plugin of SVNKit (which is not what you need here).